# Replacing a double rotation by a single rotation?

Tags: analytic-geometry, rotations

I had a test tonight and there was one problem that I couldn't even think about a solution. Problem was this, as much I can remember:

> You are doing two rotations. First one from $y$-axis to $z$-axis and then from $x$-axis to $z$-axis. Question was: in what axis you can do rotation to  replace this two rotations into only one rotation?

Answer as I can remember was the axis through the origin and $(1,-1,1)$. Would be very nice if you can explain in graphical way.

Comment: Think what happens to each axis. X goes to Z goes to -Y goes back to X. Add those three to get that $(1,-1,1)$ doesn’t change, so it must be on the axis of rotation.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Eric Can ypu please elaborate more the part how it goes to -Y and then back to X?

Comment: @Eric first rotation is from y to z then from x to z, no?

Comment: Not graphical, but for those who are familiar with quaternions, they answer the question fairly quickly: $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(1-j) \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt2}(1+i) = \frac12 (1-j+i+k)$. You also get that it's a $120$ degree rotation.

Comment: You don’t need quaternions or complicated pictures, just reasoning. (x to z)(y to z)(x axis) is (x to z)(x axis) is z axis.  (x to z)(y to z)(z axis) is (x to z)(- y axis) is - y axis. (x to z)(y to z)(- y axis) is (x to z)(- z axis) is x axis.

Comment: @Eric: I don't think I claimed anyone *needed* quaternions. It's just another route to the answer, and a rather parsimonious one (in my opinion), that's all.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn’t being critical of your solution ( and in fact it is definitely a cool way to do it), just that there’s a 10 second straightforward solution that you can do which doesn’t require any additional knowledge beyond reasoning.

Comment: To elaborate on Eric's reasoning: On a point $(x,y,z)$, the first rotation goes to $(x,-z,y)$, which follows by picturing what happens to the positive $x,y,z$ axes. The second rotation would send $(x,y,z)$ to $(-z,y,x)$. But if you apply that rotation to $(x,-z,y)$ instead, the combined rotation is $(x,y,z) \to (-y,-z, x)$, So a fixed point would have $x = z = -y$, such as $(1,-1,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

If the $y$ axis is rotated to the $z$ axis, the $x$ axis remains unchanged and the $z$ axis is rotated to the $-y$ axis. The matrix transformation for this is $$\left(\begin{matrix}1&0&0\\ 0&0&-1\\0&1&0\end{matrix}\right)$$

Then if the $x$ axis is rotated to the $z$ axis, the $y$ axis remains unchanged and the $z$ axis is rotated to the $-x$ axis. The matrix transformation for this is $$\left(\begin{matrix}0&0&-1\\0&1&0\\1&0&0\end{matrix}\right)$$

Multiplying these in the correct order gives the matrix $$\left(\begin{matrix}0&-1&0\\0&0&-1\\1&0&0\end{matrix}\right)$$

So $x$ goes to $z$, $y$ goes to $-x$ and $z$ goes to $-y$.

The rather poorly drawn diagram below shows the final result, with the axis  of rotation in blue [image]

EDIT: in response to the request for clarification from the OP, see the diagram below, where $-y$ goes to $x$ instead of $y$ goes to $-x$ (which is obviously the same). You can now see a complete circle in yellow which is in a plane perpendicular to the axis of rotation in blue. There is only one such possible axis.
[image]

Moreover it is easily verified, by calculating eigenvalues and eigenvectors that the axis of rotation is what you suspected, i.e. $$\left(\begin{matrix}1\\-1\\1\end{matrix}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain why axis of rotation in this picture is blue vector?

Comment: Also, this blue line doesn't seem right. It should be $\mathbf{i}-\mathbf{j}+\mathbf{k}$, shouldn't it?

Comment: Please see my edit. I hope this helps.

Comment: @BrianTung isn’t that what I wrote, but in column form?

Comment: @BrianTung David has placed the axes in an unconventional position.

Comment: @JohnDouma the axes are placed correctly relative to each other following the right hand rule., is that not so?

Comment: @DavidQuinn Your diagram is correct but we usually draw the positive $x$ axis pointing out of the page and the positive $y$ axis to the right.

Comment: @JohnDouma who is “we”? I have always seen it thie way I have drawn it, or with the $z$ axis pointing out of the page. It doesn’t make any difference anyway. I drew it this way so the blue axis would be more visible.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-dimensional_space This is how I have seen it in every calculus textbook I have used.

Comment: @JohnDouma: I read the axes correctly. It was hard to tell which direction the blue axis was pointed in because of the lack of referents, but I get it now (I think).